# Setting up development and production environment for android application in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I have 2 questions regarding this issue.

1. if in laravel/web we have `.env` file to set environment to "development" or production and automatically connect to different database. how about in android/kotlin/android studio?
2. and how to make my application request to my localhost (127.0.2.1) on PC if it's in "development" environment and request to real url API if it's in "production" environment. FYI, I dont use emulator. I use my phone to test my application.

Answer (score 9):

Yes this is possible in your Android application as well. You just have to modify your `build.gradle` file to manage your `BuildConfig` based on your dev, test or production environment.

Here's a sample `build.gradle` file from one of my project.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("../Path_To_KeyStore/keystore.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

def appPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("app-settings.properties")
def appProperties = new Properties()
appProperties.load(new FileInputStream(appPropertiesFile))

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    signingConfigs {
        MyAppSigningConfig {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode appProperties['app.version.code'] as int
        versionName appProperties['app.version.name']
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        def buildVariant = getBuildVariant()
        def environmentPath
        if ((buildVariant == "Release")) {
            environmentPath = appProperties["env.path.live"]
        } else if ((buildVariant == "Debug")) {
            environmentPath = appProperties["env.path.test"]
        } else {
            environmentPath = appProperties["env.path.live"]
        }

        def envPropertiesFile = rootProject.file(environmentPath)
        def envProperties = new Properties()
        envProperties.load(new FileInputStream(envPropertiesFile))
        println("buildVariant = $buildVariant")
        for (String key : envProperties.keySet()) {
            buildConfigField "String", key.replaceAll("\\.", "_").toUpperCase(), envProperties[key]
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "@string/app_name_debug_test"]
        }

        release {
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "@string/app_name"]
            signingConfig signingConfigs.MyAppSigningConfig
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

def getBuildVariant() {
    for (TaskExecutionRequest t : gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests()) {
        for (String command : t.args) {
            if (command.matches(":app:generate(.*)Sources")) {
                return command.replaceAll(":app:generate(.*)Sources", "\$1")
            } else if (command.matches(":app:assemble(.*)")) {
                return command.replaceAll(":app:assemble(.*)", "\$1")
            }
        }
    }

    return "Release"
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

I have two different build variants here. One is for release and the other is for debug. And I have three properties file in the application directory. These are as follows.

The `app-settings.properties` file looks like this.

```
app.version.code=1
app.version.name=0.0.1
env.path.live=live-env.properties
env.path.test=test-env.properties
```

The `test-env.properties` looks like

```
base.url.auth="http://localhost:8888/auth/"
base.url.communication="http://localhost:8000/communication/"
base.url.site="http://localhost:8000/"
api.key.auth="demo_key"
```

And the `live-env.properties` is like

```
base.url.auth="http://auth.yourapp.com/auth/"
base.url.communication="http://yourapp.com/communication/"
base.url.site="http://yourapp.com/"
api.key.auth="live_key1223ssHHddSSYYY"
```

So once the `build.gradle` and the application properties are setup, you need to sync with gradle to generate the `BuildConfig.java` file. You will see the file is generated automatically with the values found from your properties file.

From anywhere in your code, you might access the environment variables like the following.

```
const val BASE_URL = BuildConfig.BASE_URL_SITE
const val BASE_URL_AUTH = BuildConfig.BASE_URL_AUTH
```

Get the desired application build from the left side menu of build variants in Android Studio.

[image]

One of my colleague named Sajid Shahriar helped me to understand the setup for different build variants. Hence, I am sharing this with you. Hope that helps.

Comment: Just a FYI, with the new version of Android Studio,  Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2, the code in the method `getBuildVariant` doesn't work. It seems that the array of arguments is empty.

Comment: Another fun detail. When you change variants, the BuildConfig isn't regenerated. You must rebuild the project for it to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Add inside inside app level build.gradle file

android {
flavorDimensions "full"
productFlavors {
production {
versionCode 17
versionName "1.1.0"
dimension "full"
}
develop {
applicationId "dev.kadepay.app"
versionCode 17
versionName "1.1.0"
dimension "full"
}
}

if set up different package name
Add this line
applicationId "dev.kadepay.app"

and after sync build check build variants